# Telegram Bot revoke all invite links

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

So I created a telegram bot in py using the `python-telegram-bot' package (version 13.13).

The bot is admin of a private channel, and when contacted by the user creates a personalized link to the channel with the name of the user that requested it.

**I am trying to add a command to list all links that this bot created in the channel and revoke them. Is this possible?**

For now the only route that I thought of is to store them in a database and loop through the list using the `revoke_invite_link(link)'.

Please give me a hint to solve this, that seems an easy task!

Answer (score 1):

> For now the only route that I thought of is to store them in a database and loop through the list using the `revoke_invite_link(link)'.

This is the way to go. The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not include any functionality that allows to you revoke or even list all links that your bot created.